# go lang run a shell to check all files in a directory

Tags: go

Can someone let me know how to run "`ls *.txt`" as a shell command in go.

I have run using `exec.Command("ls", "*.txt")`, It shows *.txt file not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards like this are evaluated by the shell, not by `ls`, and `exec` does not use a shell. You could do something like:

```
exec.Command("bash", "-c", "ls *.txt")
```

**However**, it's unnecessarily complicated & inefficient to list files this way in your Go program. You'd be better served just scanning the files directly in Go using e.g. [`ReadDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir).